# Login to SharePoint Website Using Angular

Tags: angular, rest, sharepoint

All users to get connected to [My SharePoint Website](https://portal.ssor.ir/depts/helpdesk) needs specific username and password. Is there any way to login to my SharePoint website by an Angular login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a Trusted Identity Provider (also referred as Custom Security Token Service) to achieve single sign-on in SharePoint for FBA.

Details are available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdevelopersupport/creating-a-custom-identity-provider-and-integrating-with-sharepoint-to-achieve-single-sign-on-with-fba-across-multiple-web-applications